# Is this interpretation of special relativity valid?

Tags: special-relativity

Consider the following interpretation of special relativity:

Imagine that there exists in our universe a fundamental background reference frame. Photons only truly move at the speed of light within this frame.

From the perspective of an arbitrary moving reference frame, photons appear to move at the speed of light relative to the moving frame. However, this is only the case because the inverse of the effects of time dilation and length contraction mask the true speed of the photons relative to the moving frame. Nevertheless, in the context of the moving reference frame, we interpret this distorted view of the photons' actual relative speed as real.

Is there anything wrong with thinking about special relativity this way?

Comment: "The inverse of the effects of time dilation and length contraction"?

Comment: @probably_someone Time dilation and length contraction describe the appearance of a reference frame from the point of view of another reference frame. I meant the opposite of that. In other words, if we apply the moving frame's inverse Lorentz transform to the velocity of light in the stationary background frame relative to the moving frame (a velocity less than the speed of light), the result would be the a velocity with the speed of light.

Comment: @Drew That's not how inverse Lorentz transforms work (and that's also not how Lorentz transforms in general work, either). If you look at the velocity addition formula, $u=\frac{u'+v}{1+u'v/c^2}$, inputting $u'=c$ gives $u=c$ no matter what $v$ is (so an object that moves at $c$ in one frame will move at $c$ in every frame).

Comment: @Drew Also, you can't really use Lorentz transforms for objects moving at $c$, anyway. The Lorentz factor $\gamma$ is infinite for such objects. Lorentz transforms have built into them the postulate that objects traveling at $c$ will travel at $c$ in every frame.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78980/discussion-on-question-by-drew-is-this-interpretation-of-special-relativity-vali).